# Python Pandas pkl dataframe version

Tags: python, pandas, importerror

The pickle files I saved previously now could not be read back using `.read_pickle()`.
The error message I got is: `ImportError: cannot import name 'PY36'. 
The current version of Pandas is :Version: 0.23.1.`

Not sure what version was used to create the pickle files.

Please help.

Python version currently used:3.5.3 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)
Believe the old version created the pickle file is:
3.6.1 |Anaconda custom (4.4.0).

It was working before.

Additional information

```
data_cn=data_cn.append(pd.read_pickle(os.path.expanduser("~/Documents/RZSX-TF/SHF-margin.pkl")))

  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/pickle.py", line 68, in read_pickle
    """

  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/pickle.py", line 62, in try_read
    2    2    7

  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/compat/pickle_compat.py", line 117, in load
    # 19939, add timedeltaindex, float64index compat from 15998 move

  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 1043, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)

  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 1351, in load_stack_global
    self.append(self.find_class(module, name))

  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 1392, in find_class
    __import__(module, level=0)

  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pandas.core.arrays import ExtensionArray

  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .categorical import Categorical  # noqa

  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/categorical.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pandas.core.dtypes.missing import isna, notna

  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/missing.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .common import (is_string_dtype, is_datetimelike,

  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/common.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pandas.compat import (string_types, text_type, binary_type,

ImportError: cannot import name 'PY36'
```

Comment: Do you have the full traceback? What is the version of python you are using?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a version error. Since the error is `ImportError: cannot import name 'PY36'`, it means you should upgrade your version of Python to Python 3.6